# Max size of slice of string in Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I want to input 200000 space separated strings of arbitary numbers. When taking the input using `bufio.Reader` it only take a few of them. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1024*1024)
    scoresTemp := strings.Split(readLine(reader), " ")
    fmt.Println(scoresTemp)
    fmt.Println("---")
    fmt.Println(len(scoresTemp))
}

func readLine(reader *bufio.Reader) string {
    str, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
    if err == io.EOF {
        return ""
    }

    return strings.TrimRight(string(str), "\r\n")
}
```

The slice length should be 200000, but it only take 410 items. If I increase the size of reader, it would be the same. What is the max size of slice of strings in Go?, How to work on it?

Comment: I believe this is hardware dependent rather than a hard limit on the language spec. You can easily validate that slices can take more than 200000. `x := make([]string, 200000)`

Comment: Are the numbers split by spaces or by new lines ?

Comment: Actually you can run your code like this: `for((i=0;i<200000;i++)) do echo -n "x "; done | go run main.go` and you will see that it can definitely reach 200000. I think you have an issue with your input rather than slices in Go.

Comment: @Seaskyways space separated. I edit the question for the detail.

Comment: @mfathirirhas Check my answer down, if you like it, please set it as the correct answer (green checkmark)

Comment: @Seaskyways: Please don't beg for votes!

Comment: @peterSO it's called a reminder not a beg, fella. Lots, including myself, forget to mark the correct answer.

Comment: @Seaskyways: On Stack Overflow, it's begging: [Begging for Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes): "Respect is earned, not asked for."

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an issue with your input rather than on your Go code. I've tried your code on my local machine and got this result:

```
$ for((i=0;i<200000;i++)) do echo -n "x "; done | go run main.go
...
---
200001
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't iterate on the input very well. The problem isn't with slices.
Try the following code if it does what you want.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    inputScanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    inputScanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    scoresTemp := make([]string, 0, 200000)
    for inputScanner.Scan() {
        scoresTemp = append(scoresTemp, inputScanner.Text())
    }

    fmt.Println(scoresTemp)
    fmt.Println("---")
    fmt.Println(len(scoresTemp))
}
```

For the explanation:

1. `bufio.Scanner` helps "scanning" a certain input and splitting it in whichever way you like. By default it splits be new lines. Which brings us to number 2.
2. `bufio.ScanWords` is a function that splits bytes on spaces (including new-lines). This defines the behaviour of `inputScanner`.
3. Next comes the slice of strings where we store our data. It's initialized with 0 elements, and capacity of 200,000 strings. This optimizes allocation times.
4. PRINT !!

Comment: For computers you need to be precise. "spaces (including new-lines)" is precisely Unicode white space, which includes newlines.